# Office 365 - internal emails bounce back

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a really weird issue, one of our users when emailing a colleague internally via Outlook 2016 using Office 365's exchange license (Basic now I think its called), it bounces back.

There is no contacts setup for the users, the auto complete has been deleted, the emails re-added completely.

The emails to "Bob" bounce back as with an outlook bounce back not an Office 365 bounce back (checking 365 its not even hitting it), stating the below:

> > From: System Administrator
> > Sent: 20 July 2020 13:41
> > To: Admin
> > Subject: Undeliverable: test
> >
> > Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.
> > Subject:  test
> > Sent:     20/07/2020 13:41
> > The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:
> > 'bob' on 20/07/2020 13:41
> > None of your email accounts could send to this recipient.

I thought they were sending too early, but the user is advising that they are letting it resolve before sending before they get that error. Even when the user types in the full email address, they still get the bounce back so I'm lost here.

Comment: What do the logs on the server indicate the problem is?  The email that is being sent from the "System Administrator" is configured by the System Administrator.  I suspect the server is erroneously configured.  Have you contacted the System Administrator for assistance?

Answer (score 0):

To confirm if the issue is related to your Outlook desktop client, please try to log in your web mail and send the same email message to see if the issue has any difference. If the issue still exist on your web mail, I'm afraid that this issue might be related to your email account itself as Ramhound mentioned above, please contact the admin of your mailbox for help.